# Installing 2 shower heads

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure

I'm about to finish the rough plumbing in my shower, wife wants 2 shower heads. I'm fine with it, but what are the specs for the pipe size? Can I buy 2 shower valves with 1/2" inlets or do I need 3/4"?
 I am running 3/4" PEX to the first valve and plan to reduce to 1/2" at the valve. But I can do whatever is needed to keep good water pressure, including soldering copper at the valve.

Comment: How do you plan to supply hot water to this?  Also do you want lo-flo or high-flow?  It seems like hi-flo + 2 showerheads will result in short showers before tank depletion. Also, running 3/4 pipe means waiting twice as long for hot water to come.

Comment: @Harper Agreed 3/4 means more cold to eliminate before hot arrives. And you need to consider storage volume for a tank and max gpm for a tankless.

Comment: I just added two 3/4" tee ball valves right at my water heater (hot and cold) which are right outside the bathroom. Then 3/4" PEX into the room, maybe a 20' run.

Comment: Well, if the water heater is close, that helps a lot...but tank exhaustion is still an issue... With a tankless it,s an extra hard problem because it means the tankless must be big enough  or it will run tepid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*** you're going to want to make sure to balance flow***

In order to do that you will want to loop the pipes around back to itself.

[image]
[image]

If you want to make the primary loop out of three-quarter inch pipe it certainly wouldn't hurt but is probably not necessary unless you have extremely high flow shower heads.

***Edit***

**Here's a better image**
[image]
You can use one or both of the optional valves you can even go with none but then you will always have flow through both shower heads.

Sorry I tried rotating the image it keeps going upside down

**This is an example of the optional valve**[[image]][4)] https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiOycnFsPPgAhWFw4MKHSSuDd4QjB16BAgBEAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.qssupplies.co.uk%2FTaps%2FStop-Valve%2FProduct%2F485.htm&psig=AOvVaw0yBhytq_2amzj_lDQGskPk&ust=1552163162650315

Comment: Ok I've seen something similar to what you're saying, what is the legend in your drawing? I'd be happy if I can just loop 1/2" that would be easy. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Is that loop only hot water?

Comment: Adding a better picture...

Comment: For real thanks for going into that detail. Question.... Is the diverter in your pic referring to the mixing valve? As in one shower handle would turn on both shower heads every time?

Comment: Yes it's the mixing valve, and without any of the "optional" valves both shower heads will run every time.

Comment: Added a photo with the valve, it was hard to find online, I searched wall mount shower valve. Bath supply company's stock or order them to match your other hardware.

Comment: It seems odd that both heads are controlled by the same mixing valve.  I suppose it is designed for 2 people to shower at once and I would think each would want the water to be at their desired temperature.

Comment: @QuocVu that is an option as well, you would simply install a second diverter and pipe as usual for a single shower, just twice. The method outlined above is pretty common for multiple shower heads, wands and body sprays.

Comment: @JoeFala i agree with wand and body jets, but just seems strange with 2 shower heads.  Also it seems we use different terms.  What i call a diverter is a valve that redirect water into different parts of the shower and a mixing valve the one combining hot and cold water.

Comment: I guess it depends on what the individual wants. And in regards to mixing/diverting. I think the terms are interchangeable since the device that controls a shower is a mixing diverter valve. It's just a mouthful and gets worse if it's a thermostatic mixing diverter valve.